# "bash: setup:command not found" error on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd, centos5

I'm getting the folling error message when I try to use the 'setup' application on CentOS 5.5 to configure the Apache webserver.

```
bash: setup: command not found
```

However, when I tried to install it with:

```
yum install setup
```

I got the response that it was already installed and no work need to be done.

I'm logged in as root.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Many thanks

Comment: a program can very well be installed yet not in one of the directories in the path.

Comment: I have tried to use the 'find' command to look for the setup file or directory, but it can't find it anywhere on the computer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using the rpm command to query. Very useful. In the end I found out what I needed to install was an application / utility called 'setuptool' which allows you to configure various things such as the firewall etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome, good luck with the new server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this question, I thought I'd provide a bit of an explanation here even though it sounds like the OP is all set:

When you install a package using `yum`, as in:

```
yum install setup
```

You're installing a package called `setup`.  This does not necessarily mean you're installing an *application* of the same name.  In this case, `setup` is simply a low-level package that installs some necessary system configuration files.   You can see the complete contents of the package like this:

```
rpm -ql setup
```

And you can get more information about the package like this:

```
rpm -qi setup
```

This includes a description of the package:

> The setup package contains a set of important system configuration and
>   setup files, such as passwd, group, and profile.

If you want to install a particular application, you can try searching for it with `yum search`, or if you know a particular binary name you can usually provide that as an argument to `yum install`.  For example:

```
yum install /bin/zsh
```

You can work backwards and figure out what packages owns a particular file like this:

```
rpm -qf /path/to/some/file
```

For example:

```
# rpm -qf /usr/bin/ssh
openssh-clients-5.6p1-31.fc15.1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for setuptool package

> yum install setuptool

setuptool package will provide setup command for centos , fedora ,redhat & most of the rpm based distros.